# Timer wont refresh Android UI as it should

Tags: java, android, user-interface, timer

I've made an app for counting cows. Basically you have an income of cows. I use a timer to handle the income and all is working great until I change to another activity and come back to the main activity.

Once I come back to the main activity (from another activity) the double (cowCount) keeps on increasing, but my refresh() method (which is refreshing the TextView) wont run, even though it's in the same method:

```
public void Income() {

    cowCount = cowCount + income;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            refresh();
            if(timerCancel == true) {
                Thread.interrupted();
            } 
        }

    });
    }
```

This is my timer method:

```
public void startIncomeTimer() {
timerRunning = true;
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new Income(), 0, 100);
if(timerCancel == true) {
    timer.cancel();
}
}
```

The timerRunning is stated false, and timerCancel is stated true, when leaving the activity. So, why is the runOnUiThread() not executed properly?

Comment: I'm confused but timerCancel = true..? are you sure that's not supposed to be timerCancel == true?

Comment: That's correct. I still have the same problem, though.

Comment: What is this refresh() method from? I suspect that this is some view/layout, which is recreated when app is "restarted", so you call refresh on a dead view tree. You should cancel your timer on suspend or stop, and restart it on resume or start respectively